# this element might be inside iframe from different src. currently chropath doesn't support for them

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdTic.png)

**Hi Guys!
I'm trying to automate some interactions with a website. I am using Chropath to find the absolute xpath's of various elements, then interacting with them in selenium.
I want to click on a button but Chropath shows me a valid xpath.**

Add to Chrome

Comment: hello, you are new here. first introduce yourself to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and correct your answer to recieve proper help.